# Adb pull from Android Studio and database not updated in SQLiteDatabaseBrowser 3.10.1

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

I cannot see updated data in an `SQLite` database retrieved from an Android device, between 2 retrieves.

I have coded an app that writes data in a `SQLite` database on the Android device.

step1. When I retrieve the database in Android Studio with the `Device File Explorer` tool, then when I open the database on the PC with SQLiteDatabaseBrowser and I see the data correctly (the first time I retrieve the file).

step2. Then I open the app on Android, and I add data to the `SQLite` database, and I check that the data are well written on the Android device (by issuing a SQL query) and I confirm that the data are well written.

step3. Then I retrieve the database again in `Android Studio` with the `Device File Explorer` tool and open it again on the PC with `SQLiteDatabaseBrowser` but the data do not change and are the same as in step 1.

I don't understand why the data are not updated in the retrieved database file on the PC.

Comment: In device explorer are there two other files the same name suffixed with **-shm** and **-wal**? If so are the file sizes greater then 0? If so then you need to either ensure that the database has been closed (to commit the transactions and thus the files will be empty or then not exist) or copy the additional files along with the database file.

Comment: ok thanks I will try that

Comment: Yes the -shm and -wal files sizes are greater than 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .db file and the -shm file and the -wal file must be copied to the computer in order to see all the data.